How to automatedly delete broken sym links with "too many levels"?
I got myself in a state where I have thousands of sym links in a directory that have "too many levels".  I've found that find will not return them since it gets the error while searching.  I simply want to delete them, but there are other good files in the directory.  Is there a way to make find work?  Or alternatively, I have all the files in another directory and would be happy to copy over them either with real files or valid sym links.

Are they actually symlinks with too many levels, or merely recursive symlinks that somehow refer to themselves?

It's a mystery to me honestly.  They are all pointing to another particular directory (with the actual files) and I renamed that directory in an attempt to fix it, but the "too many levels" error remains.  It can't be any kind of recursion or anything if the very first thing pointed to is missing I wouldn't think.  That would just be a broken link.

Can you show a sample output of ls -l on some of those links?

I actually solved it by copying the entire directory someplace else, deleting the original and renaming back.  The busted stuff wouldn't copy.

Say you don't have the broken links now to provide more data or test solutions? In that case I'm voting to close this question as no-repro

Fair enough.  Someone else may run into this problem, but my "test environment" is no longer present.

I'd honestly work without find here. Because I know how I'd do this with the glob operators in zsh, I'd do it there; you can do it bash as well, but you'll check more things that aren't symlinks:
function check_link_depth() {
  count=0
  current_path=$1
  while [[ -h "${current_path}" ]]; do
    count=$((count + 1))
    current_path="$(readlink "${current_path}")"
    [[ $count -ge 41 ]] && return 1
  done
  return 0
}

This function keeps dereferencing symlinks, until it counts the 41. symlink in a row (40 is the limit on Linux). It returns 1 when it hits the 41, or 0 when it doesn't (or things aren't symlinks, on the way there).
I think this shell function should work on both zsh and bash.
You use it like this:
#!/usr/bin/zsh
function check_link_depth() {
… # stuff from above
}

#           /----------- **:  recursively glob
#           |    /------ (@): restrict to symlinks 
#           v   v
for link in **/*(@); do
  check_link_depth "${link}" || rm -- "${link}"
done

The same works in bash, but as far as I know, there's no type selectors for file name expansion in bash, so it'll take a bit longer, because it checks things that aren't symlinks:
#!/bin/bash

function check_link_depth() {
… # stuff from above
}

# enable recursive globbing with **
shopt -s globstar

for link in **/*; do
  check_link_depth "${link}" || rm -- "${link}"
done

However, this doesn't work when the link chains continue in the directory you're scanning themselves.
Say you have
for i in {1..400}; do                                                                                                                                                                                      
  ln -s link$((i-1)) link$((i))
done

i.e., link400 points to link399, link399 points to link398, and so on.
Problem: the moment you delete symlink "link41", symlinks link42, link43, …, link82 become "valid", because the chain is "broken" there, and they're not recursing deeper than 40 levels anymore.
Hm.
So, we need to sort the symlinks by depth first, and then delete the longest first, even if they are already deeper than 40.
Two problems:

in shell scripting, this becomes incredibly slow, my shell function above is already slow, and that is always going at most 40 level deep.
there's also the possibility you reach a ring (A->B->C->A, or simply A->B->A), and you need to catch that. And shell programming languages aren't made for this kind of checking.

OK; I can sketch a solution here, but won't code it for you.
You'll need a less restrictive programming language than shell scripting.
You'll need an associative array (a std::unorderder_map<std::string, unsigned int> in C++, a dict in Python) to store the links you've already seen and their depth.
You need to read file names from standard input, or go through a directory yourself.
For each of these file names, you check whether they already are in the map. If they're in the map, and their depth is higher than 40, delete them.
Else, if they're not in the map, check whether they are a symlink. If not, add to the map with depth 0.
If they're a symlink, create a temporary file name - depth map, and a depth counter that you set to 0.
While your target is a symlink (this is a while current file is symlink loop:)

Resolve the symlink.

increase the depth counter.
add the current symlink to the temporary map with a depth as given by the depth counter
Is the target already in the the temporary map? You found a circular chain of symlinks. Add all elements of the temporary map with a magic value "infinity" to the permanent map. Exit this loop.
Is the target already in the permanent map? In that case, add the depth of the target to the depth of all elements in your temporary map, as you add them to the permanent map. Exit this loop.
If the target is not in the permanent map, check whether it's a symlink:

if it's not, add it with depth 0 to the permanent map, and add all elements from the temporary map to the permanent map.
If it is a symlink, replace the currently considered file name with the target name, and step into the next iteration of this loop





After processing all files given to you, you have a permanent mapping file names to depth. Go through that mapping, delete all elements with depth > 40.
The trick here that makes this work is that we keep the depth information about files we'll delete. The added benefit is that you don't have to check the depth of things fully (in the example, where link50->link49->link48…, once you have already determined the depth of link47 once, determining the depth of link48 is trivial. Also, if you encounter link38 after you've encountered link39, it's guaranteed to already be in the permanent map, i.e., you don't need to check it twice. Saves a lot of time.
